# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'Where' of undefined

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, linq

I am not sure what could be the cause of this error but i am trying to return results using linq query like statement to loop through a list of positions and then another loop to get all users for each of the positions.

linq is Enumerable

```
var getList = function () {
        Ajax.Get({
            Url: ...,
            DataToSubmit: {id: properties.Id },
            DataType: "json",
            OnSuccess: function (roleData, status, jqXHR) {
                // bind role types
                bindModel(roleData);
                console.log("roles:", roleData.length);

                Ajax.Get({
                    Url: ....,
                    DataToSubmit: { pageNumber: 1, id: properties.Id },
                    DataType: "json",
                    OnSuccess: function (userData, status, jqXHR) {
                        console.log("users", userData.length);
                        var results = linq.From(roleData.RoleTypes)
                            .ForEach(userData.Users)
                            .Where('x => x.ContentRole == "' + roleData.ContentRole + '"').Any();
                        console.log(results);
})
})
```

error with:

```
var results = linq.From(roleData.RoleTypes)
                                .ForEach(userData.Users)
                                .Where('x => x.ContentRole == "' + roleData.ContentRole + '"').Any();
```

error message: 
**Uncaught Exception (js): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'Where' of undefined**

Comment: @GetArnold yes that's correct

Answer (score 1):

.Where must be getting a bool predicate, but you are passing a string to it. Try to change it to something like

```
 .Where(x => x.ContentRole == roleData.ContentRole);
```

Comment: when i changed to your suggestion i got this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token == ` and `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'Init'`

Comment: I didn't see it was linq.js. Try this: `.Where(function (x) { return x.ContentRole == roleData.ContentRole })`

Comment: i am still getting the same error i started out with. `Uncaught Exception (js): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'Where' of undefined` do i have my structure right? From, ForEach, Where - do i need to Select certain items for a return?

Comment: So i am selecting items within items (selecting users within positions) based on contentRole. Feels like i might have the ForEach statement wrong but not sure how to properly fix it

Comment: Try to use Select instead of ForEach